# Why adaptor-compatible function object can't be passed parameter as reference?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to make a function-object to take a parameter as reference, not value. If i use the function-object without `std::not1`, it works. With `std::not1`, though, it doesn't compile at all unless the parameter takes parameter as value.

The code below is from [cppreference not1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1), and i changed `LessThan7` to take the parameter `i` as reference, not value:

```
struct LessThan7 : std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int &i) const { return i < 7; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 0);

    std::cout << std::count_if(begin(v), end(v), std::not1(LessThan7())) << "\n";

    std::function<bool(int)> less_than_9 = [](int x){ return x < 9; };
    std::cout << std::count_if(begin(v), end(v), std::not1(less_than_9)) << "\n";
}
```

Why this code doesn't work?:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const LessThan7'
        {return !__pred_(__x);}
                 ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

The predicate passed to [`count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) must not modify its parameter. A parameter of type `int &` is not allowed. You should take the parameter using a const reference:

```
struct LessThan7 : std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const int &i) const { return i < 7; }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile. It seems that it isn't allowed. I want to know what happened beneath the surface—why it isn't allowed in respect to C++ syntax.

Comment: @jinbeomhong The line with the error is an implementation detail of the library. `__x` is likely either a `const int` or `const int &` to enforce the requirement that the predicate for `count_if` does not modify the value (that is stored in the container).